# Get Finalprice including tax on productpage

Tags: price, magento-1, tax, taxes

I want to get the Finalprice including tax on my productpage for a meta tag.

I currently have this, but that is the price excluding tax:

```
<?php echo number_format($_product->getpriceIncludingTax(), '2', '.', ',');?>
```

How can I display the price including tax for this meta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct solution, but some potential pointers/ideas.

Look into the tax helper class. `Mage::helper('tax');`
There is a method there `->getPrice` that *may* work for you.
There are a lot of other interesting methods to look into.

Also have a peek at `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable::getJsonConfig` in there you will see some tax related logic that may also be of use/give you some idea of what can be done.

Look towards teh middle of the method, where the code begins with `$taxCalculation = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');`

Also some potential help here: `Mage_XmlConnect_Block_Catalog_Product_Price_Default::collectProductPrices`

see the code as follows in that routine:

```
$price = $taxHelper->getPrice($product, $product->getPrice());
$regularPrice = $taxHelper->getPrice($product, $product->getPrice(), $simplePricesTax);
$finalPrice = $taxHelper->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice());
$finalPriceInclTax = $taxHelper->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), true);
```